# Rawg not returning results

Tags: api, react-tsx

I am learning react and I am following a tutorial in which I have to do this project. I need to use the Rawg API to fetch games and display them, but right now it returns undefined. I have tried using PostMan to see what the response is, and it gives me the results there.

Here is my code for App.tsx:

```js
import { Button, Grid, GridItem, Show } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React from "react";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import GameGrid from "./components/GameGrid";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Grid
      templateAreas={{
        base: `"nav" "main"`,
        lg: `"nav nav" "aside main"`,
      }}
    >
      <GridItem area="nav">
        <NavBar></NavBar>
      </GridItem>
      <Show above="lg">
        <GridItem area="aside">Aside</GridItem>
      </Show>
      <GridItem area="main">
        <GameGrid></GameGrid>
      </GridItem>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default App;
```

GameGrid.tsx:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import apiClient from "../services/api-client";
import { ListItem, UnorderedList } from "@chakra-ui/react";

interface Game {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}

interface FetchGamesResponse {
  count: number;
  result: Game[];
}

const GameGrid = () => {
  // Setup variables
  const [games, setGames] = useState<Game[]>([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  // Get games from backend
  useEffect(() => {
    apiClient
      .get<FetchGamesResponse>("/games")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("??? - " + res.data.result);
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(res.data.result);
        }, 5000);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error.message);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {error !== "" && <p>{error}</p>}
      <UnorderedList>
        {games ? (
          games.map((game) => <ListItem key={game.id}>{game.name}</ListItem>)
        ) : (
          <p>Loading...</p>
        )}
      </UnorderedList>
    </>
  );
};

export default GameGrid;
```

And lastly, api-client.ts:

```js
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.rawg.io/api",
  params: {
    key: "My API key",
  },
});
```

I have checked that the API key has enough uses, and it has well over enough. My console.log statements both say that `res.data.result` is undefined, but Postman says it is not. Can someone help me out? Thanks

Comment: console log both `res` and `res.data` first to debug. Check your console if any cors errors

Comment: I figured it out, and also res outputted what it was supposed to and res.data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that there was nothing at `res.data.result`, is because it is misspelled. You should write res.data.result**s** instead.